# Точки в названии статьи

Tags: заголовок

Заголовок статьи:
Тра-та-та. (Читая "Апофеоз" Иванова.)
Нужны ли проставленные точки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В заголовке ставятся внутренние точки, конечная - нет.

А этот заголовок так преподнесён, что никуда не деться: законченное предложение в скобках требует своей точки. А "Тра-та-та" оказалось перед скобкой - налицо парцелляция.

Без скобок было бы:

*Тра-та-та. Читая "Апофеоз" Иванова*

Comment: Я правильно  понял, что ОБЕ точки нужны?.

Comment: Рад, а куда деться? Парцелляция заголовка - это его дробление на составные. А  у нас аккурат две единицы: тра-та-та и констракшн в скобках, автором данная с прописной.

Comment: Спасибо! Поставим, не жалко...

Comment: Я если сам и ставишь, то красче было б: ***Тра-та-та, или Читая "Апофеоз" Иванова***

Comment: "Парцелляция". неужели нельзя обойтись без лишних латинизированных путанных слов?..

Comment: Это лингвистический термин, куды бечь...

Comment: Текст уже опубликован (без точек), сейчас могу только исправлять ошибки для другой публикации.

Comment: Тогда лучше не рискуй с таким проблемным заголовком, сделай на запятой без скобок.

Comment: Радик, я думаю, как старый газетный волк ("Ленинское знамя"), что отсутствие точек в опубликованном не трагедия. Это ж не столько язык, сколько дизайн... Но я бы переделала, а не со знаками проблемничала.